# Android - Default user agent for URLConnection?

Tags: android, http, default, user-agent, urlconnection

I am creating a regular HTTP connection using this code:

```
URLConnection cn = new URL( "http://...." ).openConnection();
cn.connect();
```

How do I find out the default user agent for my HTTP connection? I tried using the following codes but they all return null:

```
Log.d("My app", "User agent = " + cn.getRequestProperties().get("User-Agent"));
Log.d("My app", "User agent = " + cn.getHeaderField("User-Agent"));
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The default user agent is null because the header is empty by default. You will have to set it manually using:

```
cn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","your user agent");
```

Answer (score 6):

With default user agent:

```
URLConnection cn = new URL("http://....").openConnection();
cn.setRequestProperty("User-agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"));
cn.connect();
```